# dansguardian error: filterports must match number of filterips (pfsense)

Tags: squid, pfsense, dansguardian

Hi I'm setting up pfsense with squid3 and dansguardian packages. When I try to start the dansguardian service however, I get the following errors:

```
May 27 22:17:37 php: /pkg_edit.php: The command '/usr/local/etc/rc.d/dansguardian.sh start' returned exit code '1', the output was 'kern.ipc.somaxconn: 16384 -> 16384 kern.maxfiles: 131072 -> 131072 kern.maxfilesperproc: 104856 -> 104856 kern.threads.max_threads_per_proc: 4096 -> 4096 Starting dansguardian. filterports (2) must match number of filterips (1) Error parsing the dansguardian.conf file or other DansGuardian configuration files /usr/local/etc/rc.d/dansguardian.sh: WARNING: failed to start dansguardian'
May 27 22:17:37 root: /usr/local/etc/rc.d/dansguardian.sh: WARNING: failed to start dansguardian
May 27 22:17:37 dansguardian[52944]: Error parsing the dansguardian.conf file or other DansGuardian configuration files
May 27 22:17:37 dansguardian[52944]: filterports must match number of filterips
```

What does "filterports must match number of filterips" mean? 
Any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a pro with Dansguardian by any means, but that would appear to mean that for each port you are filtering, you need to be filtering on an IP address.

Comment: it seems the number of interfaces you want dansguardian enabled on needs an equal amount of proxy-ip's (squid) configured. With my setup however, there are indeed multiple vlan's (LAN + VPN-LAN) but only one proxy IP (situated in the LAN).